# Does a 13-month-old baby with a South African passport require a UK visitor's visa?

Tags: visas, uk, south-african-citizens

I want to take my 13 month old son to the UK for a week to visit my Grandfather. My son has a South African passport as his Father (my husband) is South African. I hold a British passport as my parents were both born in the U.K. Do I need to apply for a visa for my son?

Answer (score 5):

Yes your son will need a visa. Babies and children are not usually exempt from needing a visa if an adult would need one.

https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18